# Using multiple filters on a dynamically generated table with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, filtering

I have a table that is dynamically generated using PHP and a MySQL table/database... I also have figured out how to use filters. The problem is that it only lets you use one filter at a time... Here is a screenshot of what I mean: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTnNL.png)

You can only filter by description or by date... not both.

Is there some way to do this? I can't really provide you any HTML/JavaScript code as you won't see anything because the table data comes from a database but let me know if you need any more detail...

Thanks!

Comment: I need something but can't show anything - well, at least show what you tried :)

Comment: arrayToBeFiltered.filter((condition1)&&(condition2)) doesn't work?

Comment: "the problem is that it only lets you use one filter..." it? as in javascript or php? javascript should be able to either chain the filter.... like .filter(condition).filter(condition2)... or logically combine the conditions with the && operator, like .filter(condition&&condition2). I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question properly, you can do something like this:

Let's assume we have an array of objects

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    date: '1609084588132',
    description: 'something'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    date: '1609087588132',
    description: 'anything'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    date: '1609087588132',
    description: 'anything'
  }
]
```

And to filter this array by two properties, you can do something like:

```
const filteredData = data.filter((item) => {
  if (item.date > 'some date' && item.description.includes('anyth')) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

console.log(filteredData)
```

I think you got an idea, we filtered the array above with two conditions: **id** must be bigger than 0 and **description** string must contain 'anyth'.